# WebView in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to display a web view in Flutter for Web but I got the following error :

```
PlatformException(Unregistered factory, No factory registered for viewtype 'plugins.flutter.io/webview', null)
```

Is there a way to display a WebView in Flutter Web ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

EDIT: Here is a runnable example as of May 16, 2021:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'hello-world-html',
          (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..width = '640'
        ..height = '360'
        ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
        ..style.border = 'none');

  runApp(Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'hello-world-html'),
    ),
  ));
}
```

**The remainder of this post just replicates what's above, and is the original post by the original author**

You need at first perform platformViewRegistry:

```
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
  'hello-world-html',
  (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
    ..width = '640'
    ..height = '360'
    ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
    ..style.border = 'none');
```

Look at that [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/examples/html_platform_view/lib/main.dart). In that example old library was imported (on 29.09.19), but if you change 'flutter_web' on 'flutter' it have to work.

Also, you can use not only 'IFrameElement', it can be regular html:

```
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory("simple_div", (int viewId) {
  DivElement element = DivElement();
  ...
  return element;
```

Comment: I would just add that now, you have to do ```import 'dart:ui' as ui``` instead of ```import 'package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart' as ui```. You will have an error for ```ui.platformViewRegistry``` but it is fine. You can ignore it by adding ```// ignore: undefined_prefixed_name``` on the line above.

Comment: but dart:ui does not work for flutter web ?!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [easy_web_view](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view) plugin.

For iOS and Android, it uses the native [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin and for the Web, it does similar things from the @alex89607 answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author of it) version `6.x.x`, which introduces Web and macOS platform support!

The current latest version 6 available is [`6.0.0-beta.16`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.16).

It uses the [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) HTML element under the hood, so it's very feature-limited unfortunately.

Check the official [Setup Web online docs](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro#setup-web) to get started.

Comment: I installed the beta, it loads web inside web. The only solution I could find. Thank you gentleman

Comment: @Lorenzo Pichlli can you tell me how to allow camera permission in a webview in flutter web, the site i am opening in webview says i've not allowed the camera permission, because i am allowing the camera permission for the url on which my flutter application is running

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webview_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_web) plugin , it is an implementation of the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin for web. currently it's limited though, it only supports

- `loadRequest`
- `loadHtmlString`

Answer (score -1):

Answer by @mohamed-salah is helpful, however, I was only getting a loading symbol on my screen. We need put `webview` inside `WillPopScope` widget. Use the following code to properly load `webview` -

In `pubspec.yaml` add dependency

```
flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.9+1 // replace with latest version
```

In `StatefulWidget` class, use following code -

```
class _WebViewLoadingState extends State<Details> {
  final _webViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // on pressing back button, exiting the screen instead of showing loading symbol
    _webViewPlugin.onDestroy.listen((_) {
      if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
        // exiting the screen
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // WillPopScope will prevent loading
    return WillPopScope(
      child: WebviewScaffold(
        url: "https://www.google.com",
        withZoom: false,
        withLocalStorage: true,
        withJavascript: true,
        appCacheEnabled: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Browser"),
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () {
        return _webViewPlugin.close();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rohan Kandwal this. will not work with flutter Web as asked in the question. it will only work with flutter android and ios as mentioned in the plugin you have used

Comment: @JonStark you are correct, didn't notice Flutter web when answered.